# IntelliJ sees Object in a stream instead of proper class type

Tags: java, intellij-idea, java-8, java-stream

I have troubles with reflection, Java8 streams and IntelliJ.

```
Optional<Class> optionalAnnotationClass=...; // some initialization here
Map<Object, Object> anotherMap=new Hashmap();
Class sourceClass = MyClass.class;// some class

Arrays.asList(sourceClass.getDeclaredFields()).stream()
            .filter(field -> (!optionalAnnotationClass.isPresent() || Objects.nonNull(field.getAnnotation(optionalAnnotationClass.get()))))
            .filter(field -> filterFieldClass.length == 0 || Arrays.asList(filterFieldClass).contains(field.getType()))
            .map(field -> doSomething(sourceClass, field))
            .filter(Objects::nonNull)
            .forEach(entry -> anotherMap.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()));
```

But IntelliJ15 annoys me with the following messages

[image]

It starts complaining that `field` is an `Object` and not a `Field` starting after the first `filter`, so at line

```
.filter(field -> filterFieldClass.length == 0 || Arrays.asList(filterFieldClass).contains(field.getType()))
```

I checked the version of the project, it is with target 1.8 and uses JDK8. I invalidated the cache and restarted IntelliJ.

What's wrong?

---

Here is the full code, for completeness

```
package com.ladop;

import com.google.common.base.CaseFormat;
import com.google.common.collect.Maps;

import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.Optional;

import static com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument;

public class StaticReflectionUtils {

    public static Map<String, Object> extractStaticField(final Class<?> sourceClass,
                                                         final Optional<Class> optionalAnnotationClass,
                                                         final Class<?>... filterFieldClass) {
        final Map<String, Object> fieldNameToValue = new HashMap<>();
        Arrays.stream(sourceClass.getDeclaredFields())
                .filter(field -> !optionalAnnotationClass.isPresent() || Objects.nonNull(field.getAnnotation(optionalAnnotationClass.get())))
                .filter(field -> filterFieldClass.length == 0 || Arrays.asList(filterFieldClass).contains(field.getType()))
                .map(field -> extractFieldKeyValue(sourceClass, field))
                .filter(Objects::nonNull)
                .forEach(entry -> fieldNameToValue.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()));
        return fieldNameToValue;
    }

    public static Map.Entry<String, Object> extractFieldKeyValue(final Class<?> sourceClass,
                                                                 final Field field) {
        field.setAccessible(true);
        try {
            final String fieldName = CaseFormat.UPPER_UNDERSCORE.to(CaseFormat.UPPER_CAMEL, field.getName());
            return Maps.immutableEntry(
                    concatenate(sourceClass.getSimpleName(), fieldName), field.get(null));
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {                
        }
        return null;
    }

    protected static String concatenate(final String prefix, final String word) {
        return new StringBuilder()
                .append(prefix)
                .append("_")
                .append(word).toString();
    }

}
```

Comment: Does it compile when you use a permanent build tool as opposed to IJ? If not, the code is wrong. Perhaps you means Class<SOMETHING> as the type of sourceClass?

Comment: @bmargulies good suggestion. I run mvn clean install via command line, I get the same error, so it is not IntelliJ. Why the type of sourceClass should be important? I'm extracting the fields and iterating over them.

Comment: @bmargulies fixed (see answer), but I cannot understand what is the problem! JDK issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, change `Hashmap()` to `HashMap<>()`, and `...` to `Optional.empty()` for compilable code.

Second, your example is missing some declarations to be [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so I added this for testing:

```
private static class MyClass {}
private static Class<?>[] filterFieldClass = {};
private static Map.Entry<Object, Object> doSomething(Class<?> sourceClass, Field field) {
    return null;
}
```

**And all compile errors disappeared!** *(jdk1.8.0_91)*

So, if your code doesn't compile, the three declarations I assumed there are differently typed in your code. Most likely the `doSomething()` takes or returns different types.

**UPDATE:** Eclipse compiles ok. Compiling with `javac` 1.8.0_91 gives errors, which are eliminated by fixing the raw types, as described below.
I guess the Eclipse compiler is better*(?)* at inferring lambdas than the Oracle compiler.

---

On a side note, your code is using **raw** types. *Don't!* Change the following:

- `Optional<Class>` to `Optional<Class<? extends Annotation>>`
- `Class sourceClass` to `Class<?> sourceClass`

Also, `Arrays.asList(...).stream()` should be `Arrays.stream(...)`.

Comment: I attached the full class. I also replaced the stream as suggested.

Comment: The problem was in the raw type in the Optional. Can you explain why it wasn't working?

Comment: As soon as raw types are used (forcing unchecked conversions for applicability) the inferred signatures are erased, too. Hence the use of Object. This is done because the lack of a type argument implies that inference results can no longer be precisely relied upon.

Answer (score 0):

For such reason that I do not understand, the first filter is not liked by the JDK. I changed it by wrapping the expression into a method.
From:

```
Arrays.asList(sourceClass.getDeclaredFields()).stream()
            .filter(field -> (!optionalAnnotationClass.isPresent() || Objects.nonNull(field.getAnnotation(optionalAnnotationClass.get()))))
            .filter(field -> filterFieldClass.length == 0 || Arrays.asList(filterFieldClass).contains(field.getType()))
            .map(field -> doSomething(sourceClass, field))
            .filter(Objects::nonNull)
            .forEach(entry -> anotherMap.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()));
```

to

```
Arrays.asList(sourceClass.getDeclaredFields()).stream()
            .filter(field -> hasAnnotationIfPresent(field, optionalAnnotationClass))
            .filter(field -> filterFieldClass.length == 0 || Arrays.asList(filterFieldClass).contains(field.getType()))
            .map(field -> doSomething(sourceClass, field))
            .filter(Objects::nonNull)
            .forEach(entry -> anotherMap.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()));
```

with the method defined as:

```
private static boolean hasAnnotationIfPresent(final Field field, final Optional<Class> optionalAnnotationClass) {
    return !optionalAnnotationClass.isPresent() || Objects.nonNull(field.getAnnotation(optionalAnnotationClass.get()));
}
```